# Select every paragraph element that is not the first child of its parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the correct CSS selector, if I want to select every `<p>` that is not the first element of its parent?

Like this snippet below, just reverse! (so 'second', 'third', 'fourth' are red, 'first' is normal)

```css
p:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** negation pseudo-class. Note that when combining pseudo-classes, you must put the second pseudo-class inside of brackets as `:not(:first-of-type)`:

```css
p:not(:first-of-type) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Note that if you're specifically looking to select every element other than the first **child** of an element, you can use `:not(:first-child)`. Note that the selector goes on the **child** element in this case though, not the parent:

```css
.parent p:not(:first-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `:not(:first-child)` is a better match for the OP's question

Comment: ^ I've added that as well :)

Comment: You are correct that it's not explicitly **needed**... though I'd argue that you'd want it there most of the time. The very fact that you're denoting a `:first-child` (or `:nth-child`) almost certainly means that you want to target an element based on the parent. Sure, you may want to target **every** non-first-child `<p>` tag on the page, though personally I'd probably add a class to the first child or make use of a different tag (as it's probably a title of sorts), and then you can simply use the generic `p` selector for the other elements.

Comment: I know that we don't want to select all the p; thus we add a class to a parent to only work with these element and this is clear when we know how CSS work, but like your did in your answer we think that it's needed ... because in the first example there is no parent and the second there is a parent and you add a class, so I commented to avoid the confusion that :nth-child/first-child, etc doesn't need parent selector to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very simply:

```css
p+p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

The [**next-sibling combinator**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) targets an element that is immediately preceded by another element.

So in this case, only `p` elements following another `p` are selected. This excludes the first `p`.

You may also be interested in the [**subsequent-sibling combinator**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`), which is similar to the above, except the first element *does not need to immediately precede* the second.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.text p:not(:first-child) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why repeating the same answer? this is a simple copy past of the accepted answer without explanation